# Increasing fonts in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: macos, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I have a problem with increasing fonts in Netbeans 8.2. I tried to use [screenshot form editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22RQd.png) .but Im not able to find Fonts & Colors option in tools or menu.

I also tried to press down Alt+z and scroll up or down (mouse wheel) and also use command + but nothing happens.

With third one --fontsize (I have no idea where I should put it...). Could you help me with making fonts a bit bigger?:)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved problem:) On Mac settings are in a different place:[preferences in Netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwoEN.png)
[fonts a color changing. Netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syKg9.png)

You have to go to the left up corner, near to the apple mark, there you have NetBeans preferences. After clicking on Netbeans preferences just search for 'font' and here is font size changing option.:)

Answer (score 0):

edit: And if you didnt start a project, you need to create a new project on Netbeans then Fonts&Colors section will be available in options menu.

I think you are a mac user.
You need to look at this for config file location.
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf

And I also found this. Try this one too.
1.Use Command + , to open the options
2.Select Fonts & Colors tab
3.Click the button in the Font section (button is next to the Font textbox)
4.Change the Font, style and size as needed

Answer (score 0):

In Mac
simply click on the netbeans (upper left corner)
then-> preferences...

```
a new window will be open and select the font&color Tab
```

```
then on right side there will be a font option then click on the "..." option
```

and then change according to your wish